# MVC user TimeSpan properties limitations and dependancy on each other

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I ran into problem when creating user booking app. Basically, apart from basic property limitations like min and max value, I need one value to depend on the other. In my app, a user can book a spot at a lake for fishing. And I need it to be in whole hours. For example, if they want to start fishing at 12:40, they can end at 13:40, 14:40, 15:40, etc. How do I do that? 
My model looks like this (Rezervaces is an object in which I store user reservations):

```
public partial class Rezervaces
{
public int RezId { get; set; }
public int UserId { get; set; }
public string UserPhone { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Time of start is required")]
public System.TimeSpan TimeStart{ get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Time of finish is required")]
public System.TimeSpan TimeFinish{ get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is required")]
[Range(DateTime.Now, DateTime.MaxValue)]
public System.DateTime DateDate{ get; set; }
}
```

and my view editors look like this :

```
<divclass="form-group">
<bclass="control-labelcol-md-2">Timestart</b>
<divclass="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.TimeStart,new{htmlAttributes=
new{@class="form-control",@Value=
(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)).TimeOfDay}})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.CasOd,"",new{
@class="text-danger"})
</div>
</div>

<divclass="form-group">
<bclass="control-labelcol-md-2">Timefinish</b>
<divclass="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.TimeFinish,new{htmlAttributes
=new{@class="form-control"},@Value=
(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10).AddHours(1)).TimeOfDay})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.CasDo,"",new{
@class="text-danger"})
</div>
</div>

<divclass="form-group">
<bclass="control-labelcol-md-2">Date</b>
<divclass="col-md-10">
@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.DateDate,new{htmlAttributes=
new{@class="form-control",@Value=DateTime.Now}})
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model=>model.Datum,"",new{
@class="text-danger"})
</div>
</div>

<divclass="form-group">
<divclass="col-md-offset-2col-md-10">
<inputtype="submit"value="Addreservation"class="btnbtn-
default"style="background-color:darkseagreen;color:white"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Any help is really apprecited! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an MVC expert, but your case seems a typical server-side validation, performed in a controller action.

Look at [This example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-server-side-validation/) for a clear similar situation